# replace a word inside a string using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of a sentences which may look something like this

```
Hey {someone}, How are you?
```

or

```
Hey {someone}, Do you want to go out for lunch?
```

**[Question]**
Now I want to replace {someone} in the context with the name of a person, suppose the variable having name of the person is var personName.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Well, the regex for it is fairly simple, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex & [`.replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) you can simply use:

---

```js
const regex   = /\{someone\}/gm;
const someone = 'Jack';
let str       = 'Hey {someone}, Do you want to go out for lunch?';

str = str.replace(regex, someone);

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.replace()` as `str.replace('{someone}',name)`. If you have multiple `{someone}` in the string then use global replace like `str.replace(/{someone}/g,name)`:

```js
var str = 'Hey {someone}, How are you?';
var name = 'Jack';
var res = str.replace('{someone}',name);
console.log(res);

str = 'Hey {someone}, Do you want to go out for lunch?';
res = str.replace('{someone}',name);
console.log(res);
```